# Android - Stop Popup from closing if clicked outside of it's bounds

Tags: android, popup, onclick, touch, bounds

I've got a Popup which mostly works. If I click an item within it, it does what it should etc. 
The only problem I have is if I click outside of it, the Popup automatically closes, which isn't what I want.

```
populateListAdapter();
popuplistview.setAdapter(mAdapter2);
pw.setIgnoreCheekPress();
pw.setOutsideTouchable(false);
pw.setTouchable(true); 
pw.showAtLocation(this.findViewById(R.id.explosionlayout), Gravity.RIGHT, 0, 0); // Popup the popup!! (Show it NOW).
```

Setting setOutsideTouchable to false, seems to make no difference.

And, does anyone know what 'CheekPress' is for ?

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a Dialog instead.  The check press is an old experimental feature that is no longer used.

Comment: I moved over from Dialog to Popup, because the 'Custom Dialog' wasn't allowing me to animate it. Apparently you can animate a Dialog, but not a Custom Dialog. That command is listed as 'CheeckPress' and not 'CheckPress', and I was wondering which face the 'cheek' was on!